# Install packages with opkg

Tags: router, dd-wrt, asuswrt-merlin

I'm following instruction about [router traffic mirroring](https://www.testdevlab.com/blog/2017/08/setting-up-router-traffic-mirroring-to-wireshark/) and installation in Asus Merlin router.

Installing iptables-mod-tee:

```
opkg install iptables-mod-tee
```

Failed with error:

```
admin@RT-AC87U-A9D0:/tmp/home/root# opkg install iptables-mod-tee

Unknown package 'iptables-mod-tee'.

Collected errors:

* opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package iptables-mod-tee.

admin@RT-AC87U-A9D0:/tmp/home/root#
```

How to fix that problem?

Comment: Did you run `opkg update`?

Comment: yes, I did `opkg update`

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you were following is for openwrt, Not Merlin.

Q: How to fix that problem?
A: go to openwrt.com and install an image for your router. Then use **opkg update**, followed by **opkg install iptables-mod-tee**.